# Spring - Failed to convert property value of type java.lang.String to required type java.util.Date

Tags: spring, type-conversion

I have read some topics about this, but none of them helped me.

My problem is that the conversion is working well, but today I received a user's complaint using ios 12 and Safari. Immediately I tested on Iphone with ios 12 and I couldn't reproduce the error. 
Could it be some device specific configuration or regional settings?

Please help!
Thanks.

**Controller**

```
@Controller
public class SaleController {

    @InitBinder
    public void setPropertyBinder(WebDataBinder dataBinder) {

        //The date format to parse or output your dates
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        dateFormat.setLenient(false);

        //Create a new CustomDateEditor
        CustomDateEditor editor = new CustomDateEditor(dateFormat, true);

        //Register it as custom editor for the Date type
        dataBinder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, editor);            
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/venda3", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String venda3(@Valid @ModelAttribute("anuncioImovel") AnuncioImovel anuncioImovel, BindingResult resultImovel, Model model, Principal principal, HttpServletRequest request) {

    }    
}
```

**Model**

```
@Entity
public class AnuncioImovel {

    @Column(nullable=true)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd")
    @Past
    private Date inicioLocacao;

    @Column(nullable=true)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd")
    @Future 
    private Date terminoLocacao;

    public void setInicioLocacao(Date inicioLocacao) {      
        this.inicioLocacao = inicioLocacao;
    }

    public void setTerminoLocacao(Date terminoLocacao) {
        this.terminoLocacao = terminoLocacao;
    }
}
```

**Thymeleaf Template**

```
<!-- Início Locação -->
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="frmInicioLocacao" class="form-control-label text-primary"><strong>Início Locação</strong></label>
    <input type="date" class="form-control" id="frmInicioLocacao" name="inicioLocacao"  
           th:value="${anuncioImovel.inicioLocacao} ? ${#dates.format(anuncioImovel.inicioLocacao, 'yyyy-MM-dd')}"
           th:classappend="${#fields.hasErrors('anuncioImovel.inicioLocacao')} ? 'is-invalid' : ''"
           oninput="javascript: this.value = this.value.slice(0, 10);"/>

    <div class="invalid-feedback">
        <span th:errors="*{anuncioImovel.inicioLocacao}"></span>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Término Locação -->
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="frmTerminoLocacao" class="form-control-label text-primary"><strong>Término Locação</strong></label>
    <input type="date" class="form-control" id="frmTerminoLocacao" name="terminoLocacao" 
           th:value="${anuncioImovel.terminoLocacao} ? ${#dates.format(anuncioImovel.terminoLocacao, 'yyyy-MM-dd')}"
           th:classappend="${#fields.hasErrors('anuncioImovel.terminoLocacao')} ? 'is-invalid' : ''"
           oninput="javascript: this.value = this.value.slice(0, 10);"/>

    <div class="invalid-feedback">
        <span th:errors="*{anuncioImovel.terminoLocacao}"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Print error sent by the user**
[click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cgikd.png)

**My test**
In my test on Iphone the dates are shown this way, and the conversion works (I don't know how the date is shown on user's device):
[Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XzjWM.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Your error states that it can't parse the date format `dd/MM/yyyy`.

In your code, you are using the format `yyyy-MM-dd`.

Are you sure your are sending the right date format?

Comment: So, I have no idea why the code is trying to parse this way, when the dates are filled on his device. He was filling an empty form, so there were no dates in these fields.